# What is a proper way to remove certain HTML Tags or Brackets containing text in a QString using the Qt Library?

Tags: html, qt, markup, brackets, qregularexpression

I have a lot of unstandardised HTML (Mixed in with a bunch of Wiki markup) in which I need to strip certain tags and various brackets from it.

QRegularExpression is not the right tool for the job, as a simple string here demonstrates:

```
myString =
QString("yes<tag par1='x'>no<tag par2='y'>no</tag>no</tag>yes<tag>no</tag>yes")

// Won't work | This matches the first nested </tag>
myString.replace(QRegularExpression("<tag param1='x'>(.+?)</tag>"),"\\1")

// Won't Work | This matches the last </tag>, removing the second "yes"
myString.replace(QRegularExpression("<tag param1='x'>(.+)</tag>"),"\\1")
```

Ideally I am thinking that a function would be best, where you give 5 parameters:

```
QString stripCustomBrackets(
        QString input,                     // myString
        QRegularExpression openingBracket, // Eg. "<tag>"  or "{{["
        QRegularExpression openingIdentify,// Eg. "<tag par1='x'>"
                        // par1='x' identifies the tag to work with.

        QRegularExpression closingBracket, // Eg. "</tag>" or "]}}"
        QRegularExpression closingIdentify,// Eg. "FooBar</tag>"
                        // Means you only capture tags with FooBar at the end.

        // <tag> keep text if true </tag>
        bool capture = false) {

    QString output;
    if ( /* Number of openingBrackets equally match closingBrackets */ ) {
        if (capture) { 
            /* Do code where you leave the contents in between the brackets */ 
        } else {
            /* Do code where you remove the contents in between the brackets */
        }
        return output;

    } else {
        qDebug() << "Unable to consolidate;" << endl
                 << openingBracket << " count = " << /* count */ << endl
                 << closingBracket << " count = " << /* count */ << endl
                 << "Brackets do not match each other in number.";
        return input;
    }
}
qDebug() << stripCustomBrackets(mystring, 
    QRegularExpression("<tag"),
    QRegularExpression(" par1='x'>"),
    QRegularExpression("</tag>"),
    QRegularExpression(""),
    true);

qDebug() << stripCustomBrackets(mystring, 
    QRegularExpression("<tag"),
    QRegularExpression(" par2='y'>"),
    QRegularExpression("</tag>"),
    QRegularExpression(""),
    false);

qDebug() << stripCustomBrackets(mystring, 
    QRegularExpression("<tag"),
    QRegularExpression(" par[0-9]='[a-z]'>"),
    QRegularExpression("</tag>"),
    QRegularExpression(""),
    false); 

qDebug() << stripCustomBrackets(mystring, 
    QRegularExpression("<tag "),
    QRegularExpression(""),
    QRegularExpression("No</tag>"),
    QRegularExpression(""),
    false);
```

_

```
"yesno<tag par2='y'>no</tag>noyes<tag>no</tag>yes"

"yes<tag par1='x'>nono</tag>yes<tag>no</tag>yes"

"yesyes<tag>no</tag>yes"

"Unable to consolidate;"
"'<tag '    Count = 2"
"'No</tag>' Count = 3"
"Brackets do not match each other in number.";
"yes<tag par1='x'>no<tag par2='y'>no</tag>no</tag>yes<tag>no</tag>yes"
```

What is the most reliable and stable way to accomplish this?

Comment: How about not trying to use regexps on HTML, and use WebKit / WebEngine instead to display it?

Comment: @peppe Good question. In certain circumstances; the format presented via markup is needed for me to insert my own particulars. So for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=George_S._Patton&action=edit -- {{Redirect4|Patton|George Patton}} needs to be removed. I don't want its interpretation in my string, and I won't be able to detect it easily after webkit has rendered it. ==heading== too will also need some particulars added to it, which can't be detected via parsing the WebKit render. (I think). Make sense?

Comment: There is also the question of things like <table> tags; What if I have a table within a table? http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/tables/article.php/3479861 Removing it with Regex or a rendered webkit version will be annoying.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can't use a regular expression to parse a context-free grammar such as HTML -- any computing automata theory textbook will tell you exactly that.

So what are your options here?  There's several:

- Use [Qt WebKit's DOM API](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebkitexamples-webkitwidgets-domtraversal-example.html) to manipulate the page, then bake it back into HTML. The biggest downside here is that QtWebKit is deprecated and won't be around in future versions of Qt.
- Use Qt WebEngine or Qt WebKit and manipulate the DOM using Javascript. This is a great option if you know Javascript because it's 100% portable, and Javascript was designed specifically for tasks like this. The downside is that if the HTML has Javascript in it already, it may manipulate the page on its own.  Everything you're trying to do with regular expressions could be accomplished with [jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).
- Convert the HTML to XHTML using a third party library (TidyLib or libxml2 both ought to work) then use Qt's built-in [SAX parser](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html) to read in the XHTML document, and only [write out](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamwriter.html) the tags and such that you want to keep. The advantage of this approach is it's very lightweight and will work on mobile and embedded platforms where WebEngine and WebKit are not available. The downside is that you're left with XHTML, which may or may not be what you want.

I've used all of these approaches over the years, but these days the last approach is hands down the most efficient. That said, if implementation time is your primary concern just write the thing in Javascript and save yourself the hassle.